# How To Prove $a^3b＋b^3c＋c^3a>a^2b^2＋b^2c^2＋a^2c^2 $ if $ a > b > c > 0\,$?

Tags: inequality, sum-of-squares-method, buffalo-way

How to prove this :
$$a^3b＋b^3c＋c^3a>a^2b^2＋b^2c^2＋a^2c^2 $$
if we know: $$ a > b > c > 0 $$

**My attempt:**
$$\frac {a^3b＋b^3a}{2}>a^2b^2  
   ...(1)$$
$$\frac {b^3c＋c^3b}{2}>c^2b^2...(2)$$
$$\frac {a^3c＋c^3a}{2}>a^2c^2...(3)$$

(1) + (2)+ (3) :

$$\frac {a^3b＋b^3a＋a^3c＋c^3a＋b^3c＋c^3b}{2}>\;a^2b^2＋b^2c^2＋a^2c^2$$

$$a^3b＋b^3c＋c^3a>ab^3＋bc^3＋ca^3\\~\\ab(a^2－b^2)＋bc(b^2－c^2)>ca(a^2-c^2)\\~\\ab(a－b)(a＋b)＋bc(b－c)(b＋c)>ca(a－c)(a＋c)$$

**I appreciate your help**

Comment: Try the substitution $ b = c+x, a = c+x+y$ where $x, y > 0$. If, in the expanded form, all of the coefficients are non-negative, then the expression is positive.

Comment: @Moustapha_M_I You could have been bold to conjecture $a^3b+b^3c+c^3a > ab^3+bc^3+ca^3$. If that is proved, then together with (1), (2), (3), you got a proof.

Comment: @CalvinLin It's been a long time since you last visited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^3b-a^2b^2)>0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(2a^3b-2a^2b^2)>0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^3b+a^3c-2a^2b^2)+\sum_{cyc}(a^3b-a^3c)>0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}ab(a-b)^2+(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)(a+b+c)>0,$$ which is obvious.

I think, BW does not help for the following inequality.

> Let $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}},$ $\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}$ be sides-lengths of a triangle. Prove that:
> $$a^3b+b^3c+c^3a\geq a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2.$$

Comment: I am wondering is it possible to prove the original inequality via rearrangement inequality?

Comment: @ZFR Maybe it's possible. I don't see how.

Comment: A similar approach: $\sum (a^3b-a^2b^2) = \sum(a^3b-a^2b^2-a^2bc+ab^2c) = \sum ab(a-b)(a-c) \geq ca(c-a)(c-b)+bc(b-a)(b-c) = c(b-c)(a^2+b^2 - ab - ac) > 0 $.

Comment: @Calvin Lin It's beautiful! I think you need to post this solution.

Comment: Thank you much ❤❤

Comment: @Moustapha_M_I You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a no-brainer approach suggested by Calvin Lin, compared to Michaels Rozenberg's magical answer.

---

We will use a positive variable to stand for the difference between two given variables and then eliminate the larger one of the two given variables.

For example since $b>c$, we let $b=c+x$ where $x>0$. We will **substitute $c+x$ for $b$**, eliminating $b$. We introduce a new "free" variable, $x$, which is very easy to use since the only condition on $x$ is $x>0$.

Similarly, let $a=b+y$ where $y>0$. So, we have $a=c+x+y$. We will also  **substitute $c+x+y$ for $a$**, eliminating $a$ and welcoming the "free" variable $y$.

With some straightforward labor, we can find $\text{LHS}-\text{RHS}$ is

$$\begin{aligned}
&\quad a^2b(a-b) + b^2c(b-c) + c^2a(c-a)\\
&=(c+x+y)^2(c+x)y + (c+x)^2cx + c^2(c+x+y)(-x-y)\\
&=c^2 x^2 + c^2 x y + c^2 y^2 + c x^3 + 3 c x^2 y + 4 c x y^2 + c y^3 + x^3 y + 2 x^2 y^2 + x y^3
\end{aligned}$$

which is obvious $>0$ since all variables are $>0$.

---

Here are two exercises.

1. Suppose $a>b>c>0$. Prove $a^3b+b^3c+c^3a > ab^3+bc^3+ca^3.$
2. Suppose $a>b>c>d>0$. Prove $$a^3b+b^3c+c^3d+d^3a > a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2d^2+d^2a^2$$
   (The computation might be long and boring. The point is no magic trick is needed)